# Python - Easy - TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program to do the Sine Rule, but I get the error above, I have checked to other questions but I can't make sense of it.

```
    import math
    PI = math.pi
    x = raw_input ("To get length please enter 1, to get angle please enter 2 : ")
    while x:

    if x == "1":
        print ("This is to find a length using the Sine Rule")
        A= str(raw_input ("what is angle A?  "))
        a= str(raw_input ("what is length a?  "))
        B= str(raw_input ("what is angle B?  "))

        b = (a / math.sin((PI/180)*A)) * (math.sin((PI/180)*B))
        print (' your answer is : ', b ,'cm')
        raw_input ("press <enter> to end")

    if x == "2":
        print ("This is to find an angle using the Sine Rule")
        A= float(raw_input ("what is angle A?  "))  
        a= raw_input ("what is length a?  ")
        b= raw_input ("what is length b?  ")

        B = ( math.sin((PI/180)*A) / a) * b
        print (' your answer is : ', B ,'degrees')
    raw_input ("press <enter> to end")
```

Comment: `raw_input()` already returns strings. Why do you have `str()` around them? You probably want to do `float()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to call float() instead of str() everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
A = str(...
a = str(...
B = str(...
```

This converts them to strings. You need to convert them to floats if you want to multiply them in your equations.

In Python, strings are sequences so when you do

```
math.sin((PI/180)*A
```

you're trying to multiply a string `A` by a float.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `A`, `B`, etc. are byte-strings (and therefore sequences), and `PI` is a float.  That is where the error comes from.  To treat them as numbers you will have to convert them from byte-strings to floats, as in `math.sin(PI / 180 * float(A))`.